# Get the nearest object key from object containing multiple objects with numeric keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an object containing an undefined number of child objects which are associated by numeric values as the object keys. What I need is a way to pass in a numeric number (currency) and get the child object that is the closest to the number I pass into the function.

Example Object structure

```
{
"32.5": [
{
  "key": "value",
  "key": "value"
},
{
  "key": "value",
  "key": "value"
}
],
"34": [
{
  "key": "value",
  "key": "value"
}
],
"35.5": [
{
  "key": "value",
  "key": "value"
}
]
}
```

The keys of the object are strings, so I already figured out I probably somehow have to parse the object keys to a number for comparison but I am completely lost on how to tie it all together.

I declared a function that takes 3 parameters which at the end should return the child object where its key is the closest to my input parameter.

```
function getNearest(obj, decimalNumber, below_or_above)
```

when I put in "above" I want to get the closest key where its number value is the next higher, when I put in "below" it would return the next object where its number key is the next smaller.

If I would call getNearest(obj, 33.4, above) it should return the object with the key "34".

I hope I managed somehow to explain so everyone can understand..

This is the starting point I came up with but I don't know how to proceed from here

```
    function getNearest(obj, decimalNumber, above_or_below){
    const keys = [];
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(key =>{
        let numericKey = Number(key);
        keys.push(numericKey);
    })

    //store all numeric keys in array to further process later on
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Transform the object into an array of items using [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).
- Loop over the object using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and convert the string keys to numbers, to perform comparisons correctly.
- Sort the array by the keys using [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
- Find the key based on the `pos` argument using [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).
- Finally return the value corresponding to the found key.

```js
const 
  data = { 32.5: [{ key: "32.5" }], 34: [{ key: "34" }], 35.5: [{ key: "35.5" }] },
  getKey = (obj, target, pos) =>
    Object.entries(obj)
      .map(([k, v]) => [Number(k), v])
      .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
      .find(([k], i, a) =>
        pos === "above"
          ? k >= target
          : k <= target && (a[i + 1]?.[0] > target || i === a.length - 1)
      )?.[1];

console.log(getKey(data, 33, "above")); // [{ key: "34" }]
console.log(getKey(data, 33, "below")); // [{ key: "32.5" }]
console.log(getKey(data, 37, "above")); // undefined
console.log(getKey(data, 30, "below")); // undefined
```

Table for reference:

| target | below | above |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `0` | `undefined` | `[{ key: '32.5' }]` |
| `31.4` | `undefined` | `[{ key: '32.5' }]` |
| `32.5` | `[{ key: '32.5' }]` | `[{ key: '34' }]` |
| `32.8` | `[{ key: '32.5' }]` | `[{ key: '34' }]` |
| `33.4` | `[{ key: '32.5' }]` | `[{ key: '34' }]` |
| `34` | `[{ key: '34' }]` | `[{ key: '34' }]` |
| `35.1` | `[{ key: '34' }]` | `[{ key: '35.5' }]` |
| `35.5` | `[{ key: '35.5' }]` | `[{ key: '35.5' }]` |
| `50` | `[{ key: '35.5' }]` | `undefined` |

Comment: this returns the first smallest value, even if there are greater but smaller than the wanted ...

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry I didn't get that, can you provide a test case where this solution fails?

Comment: please have a look to the table at my answer.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks for pointing out, I've updated my answer now. Btw there's a typo in your table, `32.3` should be `32.5`.

Answer (score 1):

You could

- get keys from the object,
- map numbers,
- sort array to adjust native object sorting (positev 32 bit integer first),
- find the value by check if smaller than value or hitting last item or if the absolute delta of actual and next item is smaller.

```txt
 value   below   above
------- ------- -------                
  0     undef    32.5
 31.4   undef    32.5
 32.5    32.5    34
 32.8    32.5    34
 33.4    32.5    34
 34      34      34
 35.1    34      35.5
 35.5    35.5    35.5
 50      35.5    undef

 isAbove false    true
```

```js
const
    getKey = (object, value, isAbove) => Object
        .keys(object)
        .map(Number)
        .sort((a, b) => a - b)
        .find((v, i, a) => isAbove
            ? v >= value
            : v <= value && (a[i + 1] > value || i + 1 === a.length)
        ),
    data = { 32.5: [{}], 34: [{}], 35.5: [{}] };

console.log('below');
console.log(getKey(data, 0)); // 32.3
console.log(getKey(data, 31.4)); // 32.3
console.log(getKey(data, 32.5)); // 32.3
console.log(getKey(data, 32.8)); // 32.3
console.log(getKey(data, 33.4)); // 34
console.log(getKey(data, 34)); // 34
console.log(getKey(data, 35.1)); // 35.5
console.log(getKey(data, 35.5)); // 35.5
console.log(getKey(data, 100)); // 35.5

console.log('above');
console.log(getKey(data, 0, true)); // 32.3
console.log(getKey(data, 31.4, true)); // 32.3
console.log(getKey(data, 32.5, true)); // 32.3
console.log(getKey(data, 32.8, true)); // 32.3
console.log(getKey(data, 33.4, true)); // 34
console.log(getKey(data, 34, true)); // 34
console.log(getKey(data, 35.1, true)); // 35.5
console.log(getKey(data, 35.5, true)); // 35.5
console.log(getKey(data, 100, true)); // 35.5
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ok that looks fanzy and I dont understand much of it, does this solution somewhere takes care for wether or not I want the nearest above OR the nearest above? I dont see any param like above or below in that snippet.  Thank you for this very quick and detailed guidance

Comment: do you want to get if the value is below or above? why not check the returned value against the wanted value?

Comment: no maybe I did not explain good enough my english is not too good. I want a function that takes a param "above" or "below" and then get the nearest BELOW the number I enter to the function or in the other case when I enter "above" as a param get the nearest ABOVE the number I put in

Comment: like getNearest(objToFilter, inputNumber, above_or_below))

Comment: what value do you expect, if this is not possible?

Comment: in this case I know that there will be always values above or below what I put into the function but my fallback would have been just 0.00

Comment: All aboves are resulting in `undefined`.

Comment: sorry. please see edit. now all values should match the values in the table above.